# Can't find variable webkit on iOS 14.2

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I'm working on web app that based on AngularJS 1.7. The app is working well on Safari with iOS 12, 14.0, 14.1 - but since i've upgraded my iOS to 14.2/14.3 (checked on both of them) - i'm getting the following error :

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: webkit**

It's appears when i'm trying to call webkit - like this :

```
  try {
    webkit.messageHandlers.callback.postMessage(JSON.stringify(userData));
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('There was some problem sending message native app to IOS');

  }
```

I'm not an iOS native developer - but i'm certain that the callback function hasn't changed, as i mentioned before - it's works well on previous iOS versions...any ideas?

Comment: One of my users is seeing this too in a react based webapp. But I'm not calling anything like this myself! I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling it from window (using `window.webkit`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at least one message handler. You can do it like this:

```
  func setupWebView() {
    let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "callback")
        
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)

    self.webView?.load(URLRequest(url:url))
  }
```